# ZFS pool disappears when adding (enabling) disks to computer

Tags: ubuntu, zfs

I am adding disks to computer, not to ZFS pool.

More spesifically, I disabled other disks, then installed ZFS and created the pool. Now, when I enable the non-pool disks, the ZFS pool disappears. When I disable the non-pool disks, the ZFS pool reappears.

How do I enable non-pool disks and keep ZFS pool?

When I google this, all I get is how do add disks to a pool.

This is in Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 x64. Pool disks are 2xHGST NAS drives, other disks are just some satadisks keeping some data to be transferred to the pool.

When pool works, all works. When non-pool disks are online, even command `sudo zfs get all` does nothing.

ohto@Ohtonkone:~$ sudo zfs get all

ohto@Ohtonkone:~$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a device naming issue due to the way you enable/disable disks.

When the ZFS pool is visible, export it with the command

```
# zpool export myPool
```

Then enable the non ZFS disks and import the pool

```
# zpool import myPool
```

Comment: This works. I also learned exporting writes files to /dev/disk, so now I know to backup that too.
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-5461/gbchy/index.html